# Elasticsearch : Term query does not work

Tags: elasticsearch

I am just trying out a simple term query

```
get indexName/_search
{
  "query":{
     "term": {
            "Current Status": "Error" 
          }
    }
}
```

but it just returns all documents. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GET` (capital letters). I'm pretty sure you are using Sense.

Behind the scene Sense actually converts a GET request to a HTTP POST (given that many browsers do not support HTTP GET requests with a request body). This means that, even if you write GET, the actual http request is a POST.

With a `get` the body of the query is ignored and what reaches Elasticsearch will be a `indexName/_search` which is basically a `match_all`.